# Open a new javascript window(.open) along with its CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I'm trying to get this function to work on the website of a project I'm working on. The purpose of this function is to only (physically) print the contents of a child div which is coincidentally referred to as selector #content.

Here's the little bit I've got 'till now:

```
<script>
    function printContent() {
        window.open().document.write($("#content").html());
        window.print();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

The function is fired when a person clicks on a "print" hyperlink. The new window will load the contents of the #content div which is parsed from another HTML document:

```
<div id="content">
    <br/>
    <div id="Algemeen">
        <h3>Algemene informatie</h3>
        <fieldset id="profile">
            <img id="male" src="./images/Pixers/male_icon.jpg"></img>
            <img id="female" src="./images/Pixers/female_icon1.jpg"></img>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id ="leftbox">   
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>BSN:</label>$!person.bsn</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Voornaam: </label>$!person.first_name</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Achternaam:</label>$!person.name_prefix $!person.last_name</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Geslacht:</label>$!person.gender</div>  
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Woonadres:</label>$!person.address</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Plaatsnaam:</label>$!person.location</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Provincie:</label>$!person.province</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Postcode:</label>$!person.zipcode</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Tel. nummer thuis:</label>$!person.h_number</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Mobiel nummer:</label>$!person.mobile_nr</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Burgerlijke Stand:</label>$!person.m_status</div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>land van herkomst:</label>$!person.origin</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbox">
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Naam instantie:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Adres instantie:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Postcode instantie:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Tel. instantie:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Fax instantie:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>E-mail instantie:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>Website instantie:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>-:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>-:</label></div>
        <div id ="veldbox"><label>-:</label></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

It just won't load the styling along with it. All the contents will all just be cropped up in the top left corner. I've tried linking the CSS through JS or by just putting it in the head of the page as suggested on another page. I could be doing this wrong of course. I haven't really tried figuring this out with JQuery yet, so if you have any other solutions that might help me with my problem, I'm happy and open to receive some advice about them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: before going ahead with it, please change the id provided as veldbox. It is not a good practice to have ID multiple times in a single page. Instead of it, use class.

Comment: I had the remark a week ago, too. Thanks for pointing this out! I'll change that right away.

Comment: That is a basic prerequisite. And you can try what Reeno has provided. It will work as expected. :)

Comment: Not completely. It still won't print it correctly after hit has been formatted to the CSS styling. Your code should work, it got me in the right direction. Still, I'd like to know exactly why the page is printed this way. I'm currently looking to convert the content to a PDF file through Servoy. I should be able to do that by myself this time.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Build a complete HTML page in the opened window and reference your CSS-file there:

```
var win = window.open('','printwindow');
win.document.write('<html><head><title>Print it!</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"></head><body>');
win.document.write($("#content").html());
win.document.write('</body></html>');
win.print();
win.close();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. The CSS is loaded into the new window, which is good. When I actually print it, it won't print the page with the same layout. There's probably some obvious reason I'm too cognitively challenged for to actually be able to find out myself, haha. Enlighten me!

Comment: Don't know... Maybe the CSS styles are set for a specific media type only? `media="screen"` in the HTML or `@media screen` in the CSS file itsef?

Comment: I haven't set any media type rules yet. Would it be a good idea to add those styled selectors to it?

Comment: If you don't need them I wouldn't add them. It's hard to say why it isn't working. When the browser shows the right styles (not only the CSS file has to be loaded, also the CSS rules have to be applied to the HTML), they should also be printed correctly.

Comment: If you need to add more than one stylesheet  from the parent page and you want to add it programmatically, see my solution.

Answer (score 13):

I do something similiar to the above example but found it doesn't work in all browsers.  The following was tested with all the major browsers and works for me.  (Remember, some styles can be dependent on parent elements, so if your div is nested inside those elements the styles may not look exactly the same in the print window as on your parent page)

```
function printWithCss() {
        //Works with Chome, Firefox, IE, Safari
        //Get the HTML of div
        var title = document.title;
        var divElements = document.getElementById('printme').innerHTML;
        var printWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "");
        //open the window
        printWindow.document.open();
        //write the html to the new window, link to css file
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + title + '</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Css/site-print.css"></head><body>');
        printWindow.document.write(divElements);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        //The Timeout is ONLY to make Safari work, but it still works with FF, IE & Chrome.
        setTimeout(function() {
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
        }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know who voted you down, but I vote you up : after 3 hours of attempts, your tip eventually managed did make it work for me! Looks like it is related to the ..document.open/close part!

Comment: +1 for the setTimeout since my print preview was empty without it. Adding the setTimout allows it to render first, then print.

Comment: Good one your solution works for me thanks a ton :) setTimeout(function() { ...} works for me otherwise its showing blank page in print screen.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to have all the styles from the parent page and **print**. So I wanted to use all the *css* *links* in the *HEAD*.

My solution uses *jQuery*.

```
(function print() {
    // getting the tag element I want to print
    // cloning the content so it doesn't get messed
    // remove all the possible scripts that could be embed
    var printContents = $('body').clone().find('script').remove().end().html();

    // get all <links> and remove all the <script>'s from the header that could run on the new window
    var allLinks = $('head').clone().find('script').remove().end().html();

    // open a new window
    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
    // ready for writing
    popupWin.document.open();

    // -webkit-print-color-adjust to keep colors for the printing version
    var keepColors = '<style>body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; }</style>';

    // writing
    // onload="window.print()" to print straigthaway
    popupWin.document.write('<html><head>' + keepColors + allLinks + '</head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');

    // close for writing
    popupWin.document.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

I also had the problem with CSS loading after the page rendering, so solution was to read the css file content and write it to the new document:

```
    var w = window.open();
    jQuery.get('/styles.css', function (data) {
        w.document.write('<html><head><style>');
        w.document.write(data);
        w.document.write('</style></head><body>');
        w.document.write($('.print-content').html());
        w.document.write('</body></html>');
        w.print();
        w.close();
    });
```

Comment: how would you do this without jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. What I am finding is that it is printing before the css has time to render on the page. What I did to find this was do a setTimeout on the print call and all styling was then showing up in the printed document. If I did not do the timeout I found that the styling was not being picked up in the print call.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any one is trying to make this happen with Angular, please put your CSS file in the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to make it windows center.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=[TWEET_CONTENT_GOES_HERE]" 
  onclick="window.open(this.href, 
  'twitterwindow', 
  `top=${(screen.height - 570)/2}, left=${(screen.width - 570)/2}, width=600, 
   height=300, resizable=1`); return false;">
  Tweet this
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and it is currently working in a react app. Here is how I did it...

```
let head = document.createElement("head");
let style = document.createElement("style");
let content = document.createTextNode("")

content.textContent = document.head.innerHTML;
style.appendChild(content);


head.appendChild(style);
```