# window.open Style using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to style my window.open,

I currently have some items on my webpage that open due to a certain class that is parsed, which there after opens the specified text in a new window.

I would like to change the font-size, font and padding etc.

Here is my javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".Show a").click(function () {
        var html = $(this).parent().next("div.show-dialog").html();
        var my_window = window.open("", "mywindow1", "width=750,height=550");
        $(my_window.document).find("body").html(html);

    });
</script>
```

How do I parse css styles in javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18758370/1060487

From the answer:

Build a complete HTML page in the opened window and reference your CSS-file there:

```
var win = window.open('','printwindow');
win.document.write('<html><head><title>Print it!</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"></head><body>');
win.document.write($("#content").html());
win.document.write('</body></html>');
win.print();
win.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue a few days ago. My issue was different just to style the popup center.

Here is the code which works for me

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=[TWEET_CONTENT_GOES_HERE]" 
  onclick="window.open(this.href, 
  'twitterwindow', 
  `top=${(screen.height - 570)/2}, left=${(screen.width - 570)/2}, width=600, 
   height=300, resizable=1`); return false;">
   Tweet this
</a>
```