# Print CSS: How do I open a new tab of the current page and append CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to write a script that opens a new tab of the current page while appending print-specific CSS to the header. My JS/jQuery so far:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
/*global jQuery */
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function () {
  'use strict';
  jQuery('#print').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css">');
    return false;
  });
});
```

This produces a page with the correct print styling in the current tab. However, when I use `window.open("<myCurrentURL>", '_blank');` before `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css">');`, the print CSS is not appended to the new tab.

I'm looking for a more compact solution than [Open a new javascript window(.open) along with its CSS styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758288/open-a-new-javascript-window-open-along-with-its-css-styling) or [window.open Style using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224676/window-open-style-using-css). How would I pass this information to a new tab?

Comment: You don't. You use a media query in the same file all the other styles live in. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Or just `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">`...

Comment: Do you need to supoort older browser as e.g IE8? Otherwise use relevant CSS media query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
/*global jQuery */
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function () {
  'use strict';
  jQuery('#print').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var childWindow = window.open("<myCurrentURL>", '_blank');
    $(childWindow.document).find("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css">');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Just so you know this will not work with cross-domain calls unless it adheres to CORS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the results by changing your strategy.

1. When you open the window pass another attribute
2. In your document ready - check for that attribute and additionally check for url too if required and append the css in html.

**Please note** - As we are stuck with the strategy, hence, answered the theoretical strategy for the same. If required can add code as well.