# Creating new windows when using backbone.js and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, window.open

Currently I create a dialog box using jQuery and populate it using backbone like this:

```
$("#" + dialogID ).html(new MyView({model: MyModels}).el);


$( "#" + dialogID ).dialog({ width: 950,
                           height: 500,
                           autoOpen: true, 
                           dialogClass: dialogID,
                           position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window },
                           close: function( event, ui ){  
                                                          $(this).remove();
                                                        },
                           title: "My dialog"
                          });
```

All I want to do is make this a new window so users can move it around more liberally, so I tried:

```
var w = window.open();
var html = $("#" + dialogID).html();
$(w.document.body).html(new MyView({model: MyModels}).el);
```

This almost works. I lose my styles and some functionality is lost. Can someone suggest how to fix this snippet so that my styles and functionality is restored? (e.g. my data table styles are gone and some interaction with the elements in the original window).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Hi, sorry but this is all entangled with other code and running locally. I try to provide examples when possible but was hoping this was something obvious to do with adding windows vs just dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two possible solutions:

**1.** Create a new route in your application back end which will generate html page with just needed scripts and styles. And after it do the same as you have done but change `winsow.open('yournewroute')`.

**2.** Use method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758288/open-a-new-javascript-window-open-along-with-its-css-styling). In plain javascript it looks like

```
var w = window.open('');
w.document.write('<html><head><title>Dialog</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"></head><body>');
w.document.write(new MyView({model: MyModels}).el);
w.document.write('</body></html>');
```

You could do it with jQuery as well.

Hope it helps.

**Update**

Selecting all javascript's import tags in document:

```
var $javascriptTags = $('script[type="text/javascript"]');
$(w.document.head).append($javascriptTags);
```

Same with stylesheets:

```
var $stylesheetTags = $('link[rel="stylesheet"]');
$(w.document.head).append($stylesheetTags);
```

Comment: hi, sorry, if i have many style sheets how would i do it with jquery? thanks!

Comment: Same way as you manipulating html tags with jQuery. I have updated answer.