# While clicking flex card, open a new page and display the parsed data with style in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display the data from url:https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/digicode-interview/Q1.json. I want the parsed data to be displayed with style but, i am not able to do it with windows.open(). Could you please help me out with this.
html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickFunction(recipes){    
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow");
    //console.log(recipes);
    myWindow.document.write('<br>Name:'+recipes.name+'<br>');
    myWindow.document.write("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th></tr> 
    </table>");
    for(var i=0; i < recipes.Ingredients.length; i++){
        var name = recipes.Ingredients[i].name;
        var amount = recipes.Ingredients[i].amount;
        myWindow.document.write("<table><tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+amount+" 
         </td></tr></table>");
    }
    myWindow.document.write('<br>Steps:'+recipes.steps+'<br>');
    myWindow.document.write('<br>Similar 
    Cuisines:'+recipes.SimilarCuisines+'<br>'); 
    myWindow.document.close();
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root">
    <h1>List of Recipies</h1>
    <div class="container" id="recipebody">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

css:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background: url('cutlery.jpg');  
}
#root{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
    position: relative;
    padding:10px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 100%);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    color: white;
}
.card {
    margin:5px;    
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-gap:20px;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 8px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    transform: translate3D(0, -2px, 0);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .card{
        flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .card{
        flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 2rem);
  }
}
.card:nth-child(2n) h1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%);
}

.card:nth-child(4n) h1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fecfef 100%);
}

.card:nth-child(5n) h1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #ffc3a0 0%, #ffafbd 100%);
}
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $('.container');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url:'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/digicode-interview/Q1.json',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.recipes);
            var htmlContent="";
            for (var i=0; i<data.recipes.length;i++) {
                var recipe = data.recipes[i];

                htmlContent += "<div class=\"card\" 
             onclick='clickFunction("+JSON.stringify(data.recipes[i])+")'>";
                htmlContent += "<h1>";
                htmlContent += data.recipes[i].name
                htmlContent += "</h1>";
                htmlContent += "</div>";
            }
            document.getElementById("recipebody").innerHTML = htmlContent; 
        }
    });
});
```

I am not able to format it properly. I have looked into the other solutions, but I couldn't really connect it with the one that I am working on.

Comment: i understand that the data is shown correctly but without wished style?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758288/open-a-new-javascript-window-open-along-with-its-css-styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to open a new window you will lost the stylesheet, so you must write it in your document as follow :

```js
function clickFunction(recipes){  

    let myWindow = window.open("","Preview");
    
   
    myWindow.document.open();
     myWindow.document.write('<head>')
     myWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstyle.css">');
          
     myWindow.document.write('</head><body>')

    myWindow.document.write('<br>Name:'+recipes.name+'<br>');
    myWindow.document.write("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th></tr> </table>");
    for(var i=0; i < recipes.Ingredients.length; i++){
        var name = recipes.Ingredients[i].name;
        var amount = recipes.Ingredients[i].amount;
        myWindow.document.write("<table><tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+amount+"</td></tr></table>");
    }
    myWindow.document.write('<br>Steps:'+recipes.steps+'<br>');
    myWindow.document.write('<br>Similar Cuisines:'+recipes.SimilarCuisines+'<br>'); 
         myWindow.document.write('</body>')

    myWindow.document.close();
   }


$(function(){
    var $container = $('.container');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url:'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/digicode-interview/Q1.json',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.recipes);
            var htmlContent="";
       //          htmlContent+='<head>';
     //htmlContent+='<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">';
          
     // htmlContent+='</head><body>';
            for (var i=0; i<data.recipes.length;i++) {
                var recipe = data.recipes[i];

  htmlContent += "<div class=\"card\" onclick='clickFunction("+JSON.stringify(data.recipes[i])+")'>";
                htmlContent += "<h1>";
                htmlContent += data.recipes[i].name
                htmlContent += "</h1>";
                htmlContent += "</div>";
            }
           //  htmlContent+='</body>'
            document.getElementById("recipebody").innerHTML = htmlContent; 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background: url('cutlery.jpg');  
}
#root{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
    position: relative;
    padding:10px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #fbc2eb 0%, #a6c1ee 100%);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    color: white;
}
.card {
    margin:5px;    
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-gap:20px;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 8px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    transform: translate3D(0, -2px, 0);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .card{
        flex: 1 1 calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .card{
        flex: 1 1 calc(33% - 2rem);
  }
}
.card:nth-child(2n) h1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%);
}

.card:nth-child(4n) h1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #ff9a9e 0%, #fecfef 100%);
}

.card:nth-child(5n) h1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #ffc3a0 0%, #ffafbd 100%);
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="root">
    <h1>List of Recipies</h1>
    <div class="container" id="recipebody">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Will I be able to add a <div class='list>' inside and do styles for that ? cause, I did that and didn't get the output that i was looking for.

Comment: inside the clickFunction?

Comment: yeah. I figured it out. Thanks again.