# How to print a part of a vue component without losing the style

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing

I want to print some content from a vue component. For example from the following snippet, I would like to print the `v-card-text` element which also has an id of `#print`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    print() {
      var prtContent = document.getElementById("print");
      var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
      WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
      WinPrint.document.close();
      WinPrint.focus();
      WinPrint.print();
      WinPrint.close();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.2.0/vuetify.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-layout row justify-center>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="290">
          <v-btn slot="activator" color="primary" dark>Open Dialog</v-btn>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="headline">Print This:</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text id="print">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat @click.native="print">Print</v-btn>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-layout>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.2.0/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

However,when I get prompted for the print, all the styles associated with it goes away. How can I print a vue component in such a way so that the components won't lose the associated styles?
I recommend to copy the snippet to your local machine for the best effect.

Comment: because you open new window without injecting styles. check answers in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758288/open-a-new-javascript-window-open-along-with-its-css-styling

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to copy over the styles from the original document. Try something like this:

```es6
// Get HTML to print from element
const prtHtml = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;

// Get all stylesheets HTML
let stylesHtml = '';
for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')]) {
  stylesHtml += node.outerHTML;
}

// Open the print window
const WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

WinPrint.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ${stylesHtml}
  </head>
  <body>
    ${prtHtml}
  </body>
</html>`);

WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```

Comment: This saved me hours!  Would you happen to know how to have the icons load too? I'm using Google Material Icons and the link for the stylesheets shows up in stylesHtml but I'm just getting text. I even tried explicitly adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons"/>` to the `<head>` section of `document.write()` with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Incase you are unable to print Images, it is because when the print command is called, the image hasn't been loaded by the window. use ```js window.setTimeout(() => {WinPrint.focus(); WinPrint.print()}, 200)```

Comment: greet work, but how to close the window and keep the print dialog only ? `WinPrint.document.close();
` not working

Comment: Really great answer man!

Comment: I'm trying this on a component with a long vertical height, and the component is cutoff after page 1, with no continuation to a 2nd page. How can I deal with long "scrollable" components?

Answer (score 9):

Install this package **vue-html-to-paper**

```
npm install vue-html-to-paper
```

usage:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper';

const options = {
  name: '_blank',
  specs: [
    'fullscreen=yes',
    'titlebar=yes',
    'scrollbars=yes'
  ],
  styles: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'https://unpkg.com/kidlat-css/css/kidlat.css'
  ]
}

Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper, options);

// or, using the defaults with no stylesheet
Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper);
```

component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- SOURCE -->
    <div id="printMe">
      <h1>Print me!</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <button @click="print"></button>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      output: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    print () {
      // Pass the element id here
      this.$htmlToPaper('printMe');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

for more detail check: https://randomcodetips.com/vue-html-to-paper/

Comment: This is a good package, but how would you access and pass in the styles for your own app, rather than point it to those example CSS files?

Comment: @scipilot Facing the same issue here. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @JesilJose unfortunately no, I abandoned vue-html-to-paper and just hand-crafted a print friendly page using a specific Vue and some CCS tweaks. I tried to access the dist/CSS built by Vue but found all the name-mangling too confusing! It's a shame - it seemed a big omission for a Vue oriented component.

Answer (score 2):

this answer for VUE ONLY.
easiest way use this function.
do not call the function directly from HTML tag will not work. code as below inside a function call window.print().

```js
printDoc() { window.print(); }
```

```css
@media print {
  //use your CSS over here customize your prints components.
  ::v-deep .right-sidebar,
  ::v-deep header {
    display: none !important;
  }
  ::v-deep footer {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't follow what you're trying to tell!