# print Invoice (bill) just text in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hi i need to print Invoice  like this pic

[image]

But I take the following photo as an output, which also has an extra part

[image]

I use vue. Can you help me how to print like the first photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on something similar in php. I will post when I have it finished. This however may help.

[How to print a part of a vue component without losing the style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343006/how-to-print-a-part-of-a-vue-component-without-losing-the-style)

This link might help as well.

[How to print a part of a vue component without losing the style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343006/how-to-print-a-part-of-a-vue-component-without-losing-the-style)

It looks like an EPOS receipt (not an invoice) therefore you will need to print to an EPOS printer like an Epson TM-88VI

This library might help you with that.

https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php

Here are some more helpful tips.

https://randomcodetips.com/vue-html-to-paper/

You will still need the ESCPOS library if you want to print a receipt.