# Can't copy all the styles from the original document to implement window.print(). Localhost works fine, prod not

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have to get all styles from my Vue app. I have followed the code written here:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343006/how-to-print-a-part-of-a-vue-component-without-losing-the-style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52345332/17205118)

This isn't perfect solution but it works fine (on localhost). With this line of code:
`[...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')]`

I'm getting 60 records of stylesheets on localhost. Unfortunately, only 6 stylesheets are being applied in production (from vuetify).

Here is the implementation of the function:

```
downloadReport(): void {
      const prtHtml = window.document.getElementById("print")!.innerHTML;

      // Get all stylesheets HTML
      let stylesHtml = "";
      for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')]) {
        stylesHtml += node.outerHTML;
      }

      console.log("COUNTER: ", [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')].length);

      const winPrint = window.open("", "", "left=0,top=0,width=1500,height=800,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0")!;

      winPrint.document.write(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ${stylesHtml}
    <title>${this.fileName}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     ${prtHtml}
  </body>
</html>`);

      winPrint.document.close();
      winPrint.focus();
      winPrint.print();
      winPrint.close();
    },
```

In template I have section tag that I want to put into generated pdf file:

```
<section id="print"  class="report print-area">content</section>
```

What can I do to apply all styles in production as well?

Comment: Reason you do not just use a print stylesheet and hide all the other things you do not want printed?

Comment: I do use print media to hide/show specific elements. Just that it's not in specific print.css file but rather in component file in <style> tag. The problem was that for some reason the content of print media styles wasn't applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to put setTimeout before calling print dialog:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  winPrint.document.close();
  winPrint.focus();
  winPrint.print();
  winPrint.close();
 }, 500);
```

Now it works fine on production.