# CSS Not Appearing in Angular When Printing

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

I need to make css styles when printing in my Angular app and i decided to put the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="../style.scss">`. I have put the css styles inside the "styles.scss" but when i click the print button, the styles is still not appearing. How will i be able to fix this? Please check this link

[CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amyy4l?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
onPrint() {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('printSection').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
            <html>
      <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">
      </head>
            <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
            </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

Comment: This should help [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758288/open-a-new-javascript-window-open-along-with-its-css-styling)